# Django running on Postgre extremely slow on only 100 data

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Recently I added 100 fake data to one of my models in Django, however, now the age is taking forever, to load. for getting Post objects in my view I do:

```
posts = Post.objects.select_related('author').all().order_by('-last_edited')
```

my Post model is:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    guid_url = models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True, null=True)
    content = models.TextField(validators=[MaxLengthValidator(1200)])
    author = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_edited= models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    tags = TaggableManager(help_text="Tags", blank=True)
    likes= models.ManyToManyField(Profile, blank=True, related_name='post_likes')
```

I am using Postgre SQL as my database but I do not know what's causing this issue. Since I believe 100 data should be easily handled. Can it be because of something in my template?

Now inside my template (It is very long so I do not want the question to get messy) I have for instance liking the post, images, ... ) But I am not doing any heavy queries inside the template.

**EDIT**

I also want to add that every time my template loads I keep getting this error.

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 65283)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/apple/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/Users/apple/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/Users/apple/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/Users/apple/Documents/Project/stumatch/denvx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/Users/apple/Documents/Project/stumatch/denvx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "/Users/apple/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
```

I'd like to add that on the debugger toolbar my CPU time is 95000ms while my querytime is only 1000, I do not know if that is a lot or not?

I believe these are the additional queries:

In my template which loads every post I have:

```
{% include 'home/posts/likes.html' with post=post %}
{% include 'main/bookmark/bookmark_dropdown.html' with hid=post.get_hashid t="post" %}
```

Now inside likes.html:

I have this which I believe is accessing the database:

```
{% if request.user in post.likes.all %}
```

and in bookmarks.html:

```
{% is_bookmarked as bookmarked %}
```

Which is bookmarked is a template tag which does the following:

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def is_bookmarked(context):
    request = context['request']
    id =  hashids.decode(context['hid'])[0]
    if context['t'] == 'post':
        return BookmarkPost.objects.filter(user__id=request.user.id, obj__id=id).exists()
    elif context['t'] == 'blog':
        return BookmarkBlog.objects.filter(user__id=request.user.id, obj__id=id).exists()
    elif context['t'] == 'buzz':
        return BookmarkBuzz.objects.filter(user__id=request.user.id, obj__id=id).exists()
```

Which I believe is accessing the database as well.

Comment: try `posts = Post.objects.all().select_related('author').order_by('-last_edited')

Comment: is this solved your problem

Comment: @Pavankumar No it did not

Comment: its a bug in **django-debug-toolbar**, if you have **django-extension** installed, you can test in your shell `manage.py shell_plus --print-sql`, it will also show you how much time query really takes